# How to avoid overwriting of cell in excel using python?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am using python-2.7 and xlsxwriter for writing in excel sheet.

Following is my code...

```
 workbook = Workbook('D:\S_details.xlsx')
 sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
 rownum = 2
 colnum = 2
 for a in student_result:
     for r, row in enumerate(student_result):
             for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
                    sheet.write('A1','Student_ID',bold)
                    sheet.write('B1','Student_Link',bold)
                    sheet.write('C1','Student_Name',bold)
                    sheet.write('D1','Student_Qualification',bold)
                    sheet.write('E1','Student_Address',bold)
                    sheet.write('F1','Student_City',bold)
                    sheet.write('G1','Student_State',bold)
                    sheet.write('H1','Student_Country',bold)
                    sheet.write('I1','Student_Stream',bold)
                    sheet.write('J1','Student_Gender',bold)
                    sheet.write(r,c,col)
                    rownum = rownum + 1
                    colnum = colnum + 1
```

the code runs well but the very first entry which is retrieved from database is overwritten by the header of each column.

Hence only first entry is overwritten and rest of the entries are visible perfectly.

I am also printing the data before writing it to excel sheet but it is not showing any error nor the records are duplicated or so.

Can anyone please guide where I am going wrong...

Guidance / Help in any form is welcome.

Thank-you in advance :)

Comment: Please clarify, what is student_result, what do you expect as output, what is overwritten? Try to make a minimal example where what you're doing isn't working. You're writing fixed data to fixed cells in a loop, which seems already very strange to me. I would have expected those outside the loop.

Comment: @user3387223 - student result contains data about student. It is exactly what the excel headers are mentioned above (Student_Id,student_link..etc). My code is working fine for me just the very first entry say for eg- studdent_id = 1 and its details are been overwritten by the header itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code example:

- The headers are re-written for every iteration of the inner loop. This part of the code should be outside the loop.
- The `for a in student_result` loop is unused.
- The `row_num` and `col_num` variables are incremented but not used.
- The `enumerate()` returns a 0 row value which overwrites or is overwritten by the `A1`, `B1` entries in the headers.

Fixing these issues would give something like this:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('S_details.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Generate some sample data.
student_result = []
for num in range(1, 11):
    student_result.append([num] * 10)

# Make the columns wider so that the text is visible.
sheet.set_column('A:J', 20)

# Add some formatted headers.
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
sheet.write('A1','Student_ID',bold)
sheet.write('B1','Student_Link',bold)
sheet.write('C1','Student_Name',bold)
sheet.write('D1','Student_Qualification',bold)
sheet.write('E1','Student_Address',bold)
sheet.write('F1','Student_City',bold)
sheet.write('G1','Student_State',bold)
sheet.write('H1','Student_Country',bold)
sheet.write('I1','Student_Stream',bold)
sheet.write('J1','Student_Gender',bold)

# Write the data.
for row_num, row_data in enumerate(student_result):
    for col_num, col_data in enumerate(row_data):
        sheet.write(row_num + 1, col_num, col_data)

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Beauty is the way you explained all the minute details above. Thanks^infinity for the explanation. !!!  I wish I code and understand concepts like you.

Answer (score 0):

You preset rownum and colnum, but you're not using them in the write statement.  How about:

```
   sheet.write(rownum,colnum,col)
```

Also you probably don't want to advance rownum in the col for loop, so:

```
 for a in student_result:
     for r, row in enumerate(student_result):
             for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': 1})
                    sheet.write('A1','Student_ID',bold)
                    sheet.write('B1','Student_Link',bold)
                    sheet.write('C1','Student_Name',bold)
                    sheet.write('D1','Student_Qualification',bold)
                    sheet.write('E1','Student_Address',bold)
                    sheet.write('F1','Student_City',bold)
                    sheet.write('G1','Student_State',bold)
                    sheet.write('H1','Student_Country',bold)
                    sheet.write('I1','Student_Stream',bold)
                    sheet.write('J1','Student_Gender',bold)
                    sheet.write(rownum,colnum,col)
                    colnum = colnum + 1
              rownum += 1
```

Comment: When I use `sheet.write(r,c,col)` the records are getting placed perfectly fine. My issue is only about the first record being overwritten by the headers. Either I am not using the for loop properly or as you mentioned rownum out of the for loop can be a case. Will test and let you know. thank-you for the guidance!